# Installing different frequency RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion Dv6 2011 model notebook. I plan to upgrade the RAM in my laptop. My laptop already has 4 GB 1333 MHz RAM. My question is: can I install another RAM with different frequency, say a 1600 MHz RAM, along with the built in 4 GB 1333 MHz RAM?

My laptop specs:

- Intel Core i7 2670qm (2nd Gen)
- 4 GB RAM 1333 MHZ
- Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend it.

To start with you will need to find the exact model on HP's website and it will list compatible RAM configurations. You need to see whether it will support 1600MHz RAM at all. Many laptops do not.

If it does then you can try it - in theory the system will underclock the higher frequency RAM to match the lower frequency. In practice, this has the potential to lead to system errors.

Comment: It's rather unlikely, but even then it's fairly easily fixed. The problems would occur if the DDR3-1333 has very low timings (e.g. 7-7-7) and the DDR3-1600 has very high timings (e.g. 11-11-11). That's especially unlikely because the DDR3-1333 was bought by HP, and 3 years ago. That's not going to be the fast 7-7-7 stuff. But if it's the case, DDR3-1600 with 11-11-11 timings can run at 1333 MT with 9-9-9 timings.

Answer (score 0):

Your dv6 laptop with the i7 2670qm quad core processor can support up to 16GB ( 2 x 8GB ) 1333MHz speed only. Even if you install 1600MHz, it will operate at 1333MHz.

Better to go with dedicated 1333MHz sticks